# Ignore all in a string except whats inside [[xxxx]]

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a chat bot for Discord, its to do with a card game called "Duelyst". I've set it up so by saying
[[CardName]]
it will reply with information about the card. I'm using an npm package using Node.js.

Currently it's set up like so:

```
else if (sinput === "[[shutdown]]")
```

I was just wondering if I can use something like:

```
var lowcase = message.toLowerCase();
var sinput = lowcase.replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

which I use to remove any whitespace/capitals, to remove any text outside of [[xxx]] so that someone can call it in a sentence. Right now you need to call what's in the IF (excluding capitals and whitespace).

example chat text

"what do you guys think of [[astral]] i think its cool"

so i'd like to be able to modify the string to remove anything around [[]]

Comment: Use `/(\[\[.+?\]\])/gi` as your regexp. It should return all matches (maybe more than one). Also the `i` flag will make it case insensitive, probably obsoleting your `.toLowerCase()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a different approach: pull out anything enclosed within `[[]]` then act upon it:

```js
    var message = "hello [[xxx]] bye [[ZZZ]]"
    
    var result, re = /\[\[(.*?)\]\]/g;
    while ((result = re.exec(message)) != null) {
        switch (result[1].toLowerCase()) {

            case "xxx":
                console.log("found xxx");
                break;

            case "zzz":
                console.log("found zzz");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: this seems to stop running after zzz is detected? but xxx being found doesnt end the code

Comment: After zzz there is nothing else to detect?

Comment: its a chat bot, so it runs forever xD, but i just put

case "asdasfasffs":

since that will never proc it will continue to run

Comment: hey again, could this also be setup to read [[xxx]] and (xxx)? or would i just have to remake the while?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var str = "This is just [[Testing]] for you";
    var str = str.toLowerCase();
    var regExp = /\[\[([^)]+)\]\]/;
    var matches = regExp.exec(str);
    alert(matches[0]);
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1t4n65b7/